# Including unobtrusive-ajax making all scripts stop working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I having a issue while bundling by JavaScript files through Bundling in `.NET MVC4`

I am adding following scripts to bundle up in my code

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundle").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js","~/Scripts/kui/kendo.all.min.js", "~/Scripts/kui/kendo.grid.min.js", "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"));
```

Everything works fine till here, but When I Add `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` to the list:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundle ").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js","~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js","~/Scripts/kui/kendo.all.min.js", "~/Scripts/kui/kendo.grid.min.js", "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"));
```

All scripts stops working (Validation, Kendo UI etc.) and I get this exception through Visual Studio JS debugger:
`Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method`

With below code highlighted in the generated bundles script file:

```
n("a[data-ajax=true]").live("click",function(n){n.preventDefault(),r(this,{url:this.href,type:"GET",data:[]})}),n("form[data-ajax=true] input[type=image]").live( ….
```

And on moving forward nothing (JavaScript/Jquery related) works anymore.

Probably there is conflict in JS file with var or function names? But it’s very hard to trace out in a long minified and bundled script file.
Kindly help.

Comment: i think `.live` is depricated in jquery 1.9 version. Try removing the live function and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the `live` function has been REMOVED in jQuery v1.9.

You can try changing `.live` to `.on`.

Or, try to update the jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax NuGet package.

Comment: The latest version on NuGet is `2.0.20710.0` last updated on `August 11, 2012` which is way prior to the jQuery v1.9 release so i don't think updating it would work?

Comment: @SajjadHashmi I've just tested updating jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax NuGet package on a test MVC 4 project, and it works. The new version is 2.0.30116.0 and it's been updated on Feb 18, 2013. It uses the .on function.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

replace

```
$("a[data-ajax=true]").live("click",function(n){});
```

with

```
$("a[data-ajax=true]").on("click",function(n){});
```

Hope it helps